# Are DME arcs coded in the CIFP data file?

Tags: instrument-procedures

I use a git project (https://github.com/rstory1/parseCifp) to transfer the FAA CIFP formatted file into a database, but noticed that DME arcs don't seem to be carried over. Looking into the FAACIFP18 file, I can't seem to find it either for some sample airports (e.g. KMTN). Any FAACIFP experts who can chime in on where exactly they are published in this cryptic format, if at all?

Comment: Are you talking about the KMTN VOR DME 15 approach?  This is the DME approach to a runway.  It is the only procedure I have ever seen like this?  The procedure is also not in an GPS or FMS that I am aware of.